# How to avoid overwriting of a JSON object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript, tsx

I'm comparing two JSON and returning mismatched values from the second JSON with a key and storing them in a new JSON object. I'm using a loop for comparing two JSON objects. If there is more than one difference, it is overwritten by the previous object stored. Can you please tell me how to resolve it?

```
    var finalOutputJson;
let jsonOutput1 = {},
  jsonOutput2 = {};


for (let i of jsonData1) {
      var d = jsonData2.filter(
        (data) => data.Unique == i.Unique
      );      
      if (d != []) {
        let keys = Object.keys(i);
        for (let j of keys) {
          if (j == "Title") {
            if (i[j] != d[0]["Name"].Title) {          
             jsonOutput1 = { [j]: d[0]["Name"].Title };
              console.log(jsonOutput1);
            }
          } else if (i[j] != d[0][j]) {            
            jsonOutput2 = { [j]: d[0][j] };            
            console.log(jsonOutput2);
          }


[![jsonOutput1][1]][1]
```

[image: jsonOutput2]

inputJsonData1 :-

```
[
    {
        "Title": "Ankit Singh1",
        "Aadhar_x0020_Nuber": 999941057058,
        "Age": 54,
        "Gender": "M",
        "Phone": 2810806979,
        "Father_x0020_Name": "Mr. Choudhury",
        "Email": "sschoudhury@dummyemail.com",
        "City": "New Delhi",
        "State": "New delhi"
    },
    {
        "Title": "Munendra",
        "Aadhar_x0020_Nuber": 999971658847,
        "Age": 44,
        "Gender": "M",
        "Phone": 2314475929,
        "Father_x0020_Name": "Mr. Agarwal",
        "Email": "kma@mailserver.com",
        "City": "Udaipur",
        "State": "Rajasthan"
    },
    {
        "Title": "Mayank Sharma3",
        "Aadhar_x0020_Nuber": 999933119405,
        "Age": 79,
        "Gender": "F",
        "Phone": 2837032088,
        "Father_x0020_Name": "Mr. Bedi",
        "Email": "bedi2020@mailserver.com",
        "City": "Bareilly",
        "State": "Uttar Pradesh"
    },
    {
        "Title": "Shikhar Saxena5",
        "Aadhar_x0020_Nuber": 999955183433,
        "Age": 37,
        "Gender": "M",
        "Phone": 2821096353,
        "Father_x0020_Name": "Mr. Pandey",
        "Email": "rpandey@mailserver.com",
        "City": "Mumbai",
        "State": "Maharastra"
    },
    {
        "Title": "Namita Rastogi",
        "Aadhar_x0020_Nuber": 999990501894,
        "Age": 40,
        "Gender": "F",
        "Phone": 2821096350,
        "Father_x0020_Name": "Mr. Kapoor",
        "Email": "anisha@gmail.com",
        "City": "Bangalore",
        "State": "Karnataka"
    }
]
```

inputJsonData2:-

```
[
    {
        "odata.type": "SP.Data.Aadhar_x005f_DataListItem",
        "odata.id": "1a8bda26-b339-4e95-a42e-cf8b15aa571c",
        "odata.etag": "\"3\"",
        "odata.editLink": "Web/Lists(guid'f57b8a37-9a12-48fa-ae4a-f2c360611fd2')/Items(1)",
        "Name@odata.navigationLinkUrl": "Web/Lists(guid'f57b8a37-9a12-48fa-ae4a-f2c360611fd2')/Items(1)/Name",
        "Name": {
            "odata.type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem",
            "odata.id": "e0fc5839-8528-460f-9a97-735b3e676870",
            "Title": "Ankit Singh"
        },
        "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
        "Id": 1,
        "ServerRedirectedEmbedUri": null,
        "ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl": "",
        "ID": 1,
        "ContentTypeId": "0x0100CAEC71E55732C14BA36095D2FA8E6CA80037B4C7B1E7CFFA4D83E55D30CD77AC99",
        "Title": null,
        "Modified": "2022-06-07T09:31:14Z",
        "Created": "2022-06-02T08:15:05Z",
        "AuthorId": 1282,
        "EditorId": 1282,
        "OData__UIVersionString": "3.0",
        "Attachments": false,
        "GUID": "c27f786a-8599-400c-b284-f7bec308a861",
        "ComplianceAssetId": null,
        "Aadhar_x0020_Nuber": 999941057058,
        "NameId": 1282,
        "NameStringId": "1282",
        "Age": 54,
        "Gender": "M",
        "Phone": 2810806979,
        "Father_x0020_Name": "Mr. Choudhury",
        "Email": "sschoudhury@dummyemail.com",
        "City": "New Delhi",
        "State": "New delhi"
    },
    {
        "odata.type": "SP.Data.Aadhar_x005f_DataListItem",
        "odata.id": "bbb3d19c-5fae-463b-993a-08e3665f4997",
        "odata.etag": "\"2\"",
        "odata.editLink": "Web/Lists(guid'f57b8a37-9a12-48fa-ae4a-f2c360611fd2')/Items(2)",
        "Name@odata.navigationLinkUrl": "Web/Lists(guid'f57b8a37-9a12-48fa-ae4a-f2c360611fd2')/Items(2)/Name",
        "Name": {
            "odata.type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem",
            "odata.id": "f9f74da9-4aba-4cdc-8e4f-2985883c4602",
            "Title": "Munendra"
        },
        "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
        "Id": 2,
        "ServerRedirectedEmbedUri": null,
        "ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl": "",
        "ID": 2,
        "ContentTypeId": "0x0100CAEC71E55732C14BA36095D2FA8E6CA80037B4C7B1E7CFFA4D83E55D30CD77AC99",
        "Title": null,
        "Modified": "2022-06-16T06:40:16Z",
        "Created": "2022-06-02T08:17:48Z",
        "AuthorId": 1282,
        "EditorId": 1282,
        "OData__UIVersionString": "2.0",
        "Attachments": false,
        "GUID": "afb84bd6-0253-4bf8-a515-824b13ae1a4e",
        "ComplianceAssetId": null,
        "Aadhar_x0020_Nuber": 999971658847,
        "NameId": 107,
        "NameStringId": "107",
        "Age": 44,
        "Gender": "F",
        "Phone": 2314475929,
        "Father_x0020_Name": "Mr. Agarwal",
        "Email": "kma@mailserver.com",
        "City": "Udaipur",
        "State": "Rajasthan"
    },
    {
        "odata.type": "SP.Data.Aadhar_x005f_DataListItem",
        "odata.id": "49217d7e-200c-496b-b728-bd5307bbe1db",
        "odata.etag": "\"1\"",
        "odata.editLink": "Web/Lists(guid'f57b8a37-9a12-48fa-ae4a-f2c360611fd2')/Items(3)",
        "Name@odata.navigationLinkUrl": "Web/Lists(guid'f57b8a37-9a12-48fa-ae4a-f2c360611fd2')/Items(3)/Name",
        "Name": {
            "odata.type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem",
            "odata.id": "df5b1286-0009-48ba-a7bc-7b269a9ebcf7",
            "Title": "Mayank Sharma3"
        },
        "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
        "Id": 3,
        "ServerRedirectedEmbedUri": null,
        "ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl": "",
        "ID": 3,
        "ContentTypeId": "0x0100CAEC71E55732C14BA36095D2FA8E6CA80037B4C7B1E7CFFA4D83E55D30CD77AC99",
        "Title": null,
        "Modified": "2022-06-02T08:18:58Z",
        "Created": "2022-06-02T08:18:58Z",
        "AuthorId": 1282,
        "EditorId": 1282,
        "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
        "Attachments": false,
        "GUID": "e5ac3af3-e024-4703-b946-96cdc2ff3b5e",
        "ComplianceAssetId": null,
        "Aadhar_x0020_Nuber": 999933119405,
        "NameId": 705,
        "NameStringId": "705",
        "Age": 79,
        "Gender": "M",
        "Phone": 2837032088,
        "Father_x0020_Name": "Mr. Bedi",
        "Email": "bedi2020@mailserver.com",
        "City": "Bareilly",
        "State": "Uttar Pradesh"
    },
    {
        "odata.type": "SP.Data.Aadhar_x005f_DataListItem",
        "odata.id": "e1f7ffaa-1bc7-4afa-bccb-18965f13c750",
        "odata.etag": "\"1\"",
        "odata.editLink": "Web/Lists(guid'f57b8a37-9a12-48fa-ae4a-f2c360611fd2')/Items(4)",
        "Name@odata.navigationLinkUrl": "Web/Lists(guid'f57b8a37-9a12-48fa-ae4a-f2c360611fd2')/Items(4)/Name",
        "Name": {
            "odata.type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem",
            "odata.id": "5f9e7c49-9bde-4b66-90c8-12e156db60ce",
            "Title": "Shikhar Saxena"
        },
        "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
        "Id": 4,
        "ServerRedirectedEmbedUri": null,
        "ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl": "",
        "ID": 4,
        "ContentTypeId": "0x0100CAEC71E55732C14BA36095D2FA8E6CA80037B4C7B1E7CFFA4D83E55D30CD77AC99",
        "Title": null,
        "Modified": "2022-06-02T08:20:16Z",
        "Created": "2022-06-02T08:20:16Z",
        "AuthorId": 1282,
        "EditorId": 1282,
        "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
        "Attachments": false,
        "GUID": "c3395b35-a981-4754-abb5-8b4b0fe65a51",
        "ComplianceAssetId": null,
        "Aadhar_x0020_Nuber": 999955183433,
        "NameId": 846,
        "NameStringId": "846",
        "Age": 37,
        "Gender": "M",
        "Phone": 2821096353,
        "Father_x0020_Name": "Mr. Pandey",
        "Email": "rpandey@mailserver.com",
        "City": "Mumbai",
        "State": "Maharastra"
    },
    {
        "odata.type": "SP.Data.Aadhar_x005f_DataListItem",
        "odata.id": "29ba7f05-52e8-4ded-b3e5-22a9b3001d97",
        "odata.etag": "\"2\"",
        "odata.editLink": "Web/Lists(guid'f57b8a37-9a12-48fa-ae4a-f2c360611fd2')/Items(5)",
        "Name@odata.navigationLinkUrl": "Web/Lists(guid'f57b8a37-9a12-48fa-ae4a-f2c360611fd2')/Items(5)/Name",
        "Name": {
            "odata.type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem",
            "odata.id": "cdce69d7-a601-4c9f-ad03-0a85eccb510b",
            "Title": "Namita Rastogi"
        },
        "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
        "Id": 5,
        "ServerRedirectedEmbedUri": null,
        "ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl": "",
        "ID": 5,
        "ContentTypeId": "0x0100CAEC71E55732C14BA36095D2FA8E6CA80037B4C7B1E7CFFA4D83E55D30CD77AC99",
        "Title": null,
        "Modified": "2022-06-09T07:25:17Z",
        "Created": "2022-06-02T08:21:46Z",
        "AuthorId": 1282,
        "EditorId": 1282,
        "OData__UIVersionString": "2.0",
        "Attachments": false,
        "GUID": "7a7d7906-442e-41eb-9f17-16f729fbb310",
        "ComplianceAssetId": null,
        "Aadhar_x0020_Nuber": 999990501894,
        "NameId": 849,
        "NameStringId": "849",
        "Age": 40,
        "Gender": "F",
        "Phone": 2821096351,
        "Father_x0020_Name": "Mr. Kapoor",
        "Email": "anisha@gmail.com",
        "City": "Bangalore",
        "State": "Karnataka"
    }
]
```

Expected Output:-

```
[
    {
        "Title": "Ankit Singh",
        "Aadhar_x0020_Nuber": ,
        "Age": ,
        "Gender": "",
        "Phone": ,
        "Father_x0020_Name": "",
        "Email": "",
        "City": "",
        "State": ""
    },
    {
        "Title": "",
        "Aadhar_x0020_Nuber": ,
        "Age": ,
        "Gender": "F",
        "Phone": ,
        "Father_x0020_Name": "",
        "Email": "",
        "City": "",
        "State": ""
    },
    {
        "Title": "",
        "Aadhar_x0020_Nuber": ,
        "Age": ,
        "Gender": "M",
        "Phone": ,
        "Father_x0020_Name": "",
        "Email": "",
        "City": "",
        "State": ""
    },
    {
        "Title": "Shikhar Saxena",
        "Aadhar_x0020_Nuber": ,
        "Age": ,
        "Gender": "",
        "Phone": ,
        "Father_x0020_Name": "",
        "Email": "",
        "City": "",
        "State": ""
    },
    {
        "Title": "",
        "Aadhar_x0020_Nuber": ,
        "Age": ,
        "Gender": "",
        "Phone": 2821096351,
        "Father_x0020_Name": "",
        "Email": "",
        "City": "",
        "State": ""
    }
]
```

Comment: Provide some input data and the expected output data that would be helpful

Comment: @ShubhamSogi I've added the input json's and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a new value to the `jsonOutput1` and `jsonOutput2` everytime. You want to add to the existing object, in that case you need to change the lines:

```js
jsonOutput1 = { [j]: d[0]["Name"].Title };
```

to

```js
jsonOutput1[j] = d[0]["Name"].Title;
```

Similarly update the code for your `jsonOutput2` line as well.

You can refer to this [MDN JavaScript Guide Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) and refer to the part where there demonstrate how to create additional properties in an existing object.

Hopefully, this will work.